# NSDirectoryEnumerator not looping; only processing one file at a time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm writing a program that loops through and deletes all of the files in a folder. I'm using `NSDirectoryEnumerator` to do so. Problem is, the code only loops through once, handling one file, and then exists. I know this from NSLog statements. It works with single files and a folder with a single file in it.

Here's the relevant code:

```
NSString *fileToNuke = filePath;
NSLog(@"Incinerating %@", fileToNuke);
[spinner startAnimation:self];
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"Incinerating %i times.", timesToIncinerate);
#endif

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NULL] && isDir) {
        NSDirectoryEnumerator *directoryEnumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtPath:filePath];
        //NSString *file;

        //file = [directoryEnumerator nextObject];
        for (NSString *file in directoryEnumerator) {
            // Construct the path of the file to incinerate.
            NSString *finalPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", filePath, file];
#ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog(@"%@", finalPath);
#endif

            if (!incinerate(timesToIncinerate, [finalPath cStringUsingEncoding:(NSASCIIStringEncoding)], (int)eraseFile, useNonBlockingRandom, incinerateCallback)) {
                [spinner stopAnimation:self];
                erasing = NO;
                break;
            }
            [spinner stopAnimation:self];
            erasing = NO;

            //file = [directoryEnumerator nextObject];
        }
    } else if (!isDir) {
        if (!incinerate(timesToIncinerate, [fileToNuke cStringUsingEncoding:(NSASCIIStringEncoding)], (int)eraseFile, useNonBlockingRandom, incinerateCallback)) {
            [spinner stopAnimation:self];
        }
        [spinner stopAnimation:self];
        erasing = NO;
}

// Tell the application waiting on the main thread to finish up with our task by notifing the user of
// our completion.
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(finishIncineration) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

I suspect it has something to do with how my `while` loop is being set up, but I welcome any suggestions. I just *know* I'm doing something stupid...

Comment: By the way, this may be significant: `if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NULL] && isDir) {`

Comment: Also, depending on how you initialize `isDir`, this may behave weirdly when the item already doesn't exist. `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` is not guaranteed to tell you whether the item might hypothetically have been a directory or not if the item doesn't exist. Store the result of that method in a variable, then test `exists && isDir` first and `exists && !isDir` second.

Comment: And other problems. You're using `stringWithFormat:` to staple paths together (there are dedicated methods for that). You're encoding paths as ASCII rather than UTF-8 (or, better yet, `fileSystemRepresentation`, or, better yet, leaving them as NSStrings). You stop the animation in four places and set `erasing = NO` in three, with no apparent pattern. Plus, I don't see where `erasing` is ever set to `YES` (before this code?) or read.

Comment: What does `incinerate` return? Not just what type, but what values, and in which circumstances?

Comment: Does the NSLog(finalPath) print once? If so, then the obvious way to stop the `for (file in directoryEnumerator)` loop early is that `break` statement. Check that first. You should also set a breakpoint at the top of this code, use Step Over in the debugger to run it one line at a time, and watch for the execution to do something you don't expect.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Turns out the problem was that `break` statement was being called when it shouldn't have been. I think I can get it from here. I'll take your suggestions into account, however.